# Filter multiple levels of character data

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a dataframe and am trying to select certain character levels from two columns of my dataframe but am having some problems getting the syntax to work/produce the correct output. Example dataframe:

```
Land <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A") 
Activity <- c("low", "low", "high", "low", "medium", "high", "high", "high", "medium") 
df <- data.frame(Land, Activity)
```

I want to filter to get Land 'A' and with Part Activity 'high' or 'medium'. I've tried the following code to filter under a certain land use and then get either 'high' OR 'medium' but it only ever sorts Land 'A' and Activity 'high'.

```
 df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(Land == "A") %>% 
  filter(Activity == "high" | Activity =="medium")
```

In place of that third line (`filter(Activity == "high" | Activity =="medium")`) I've also tried `filter(Activity == "high" & Activity =="medium")` and `filter(Activity != "low" | Activity !="none")` but it still does not filter for all the Activity levels I want. How do I fix my code to filter both these character factors?

Edit:
I'd like to have a table that looks as follows:

```
Land Activity 
A     high
A     high
A     medium
```

Edit:
Current output:

```
Land Activity 
A     high
A     high
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the expected

Comment: I also suspect if this a case of not loading the `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Just edited post to show what I expect/want. I do have the library(dplyr) loaded.

Comment: If that is the case, your code is giving me the correct one.

Comment: Can you show what you are getting as output with that code.  I am assuming that there is some masking of `filter` from another package.  Then, use `dplyr::filter` explicitly

Comment: Just edited again, my output is just the first variable of my filter for Activity. I'm not sure why it isn't filtering for multiple conditions when I use the OR (`|`) statement.

Comment: I am using `R 4.1.0` with `dplyr` 1.0.6.  Can you try this on a fresh R session with only `library(dplyr)` loaded

Comment: Restarting R did fix it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to keep the rest of the 'Land' as well, use an OR (`|`) condition where 'Land' is not equal to 'A'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    filter((Land == 'A' & Activity %in% c("high", "medium")) | Land != "A")
```

-output

```
   Land Activity
1    B      low
2    C     high
3    B   medium
4    C     high
5    A     high
6    A     high
7    A   medium
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's comments, the `filter` is working as expected

```
df %>% 
  filter(Land == "A") %>% 
  filter(Activity == "high" | Activity =="medium") 
 Land Activity
1    A     high
2    A     high
3    A   medium
```